# What skills are good choices for Training?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since it seems just about any skill can be power-leveled, I would like to know which takes the longest so i can use my fortune to pay a trainer to help me out.

Which skills are hardest to level "manually", and could most stand to benefit from free levels from training?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what your current skills are and what level they are at, and then it would be too specific to be a good question for this site, imo.

Comment: My apologies, first time here and already impressedAlteration 100, Enchanting 100, Smithing 100, Heavy Armor 25, Block 64, Two-Handed 37, One-Handed 100, Archery 21, Light Armor 49, Sneak 61, Lockpicking 100, Pickpocket 26, Speech ~70, Alchemy 26, Illusion 67, Conjuration 57, Destruction 66 and Restoration 70

Comment: Wow, I sure am proving myself to be a n00b here, lol. I understand what you mean by too specific so hopefully my question is better now. As for my comment above, I leaned two things: 5 minute window and you cant go back and hit return. thanks for the input Victoriah

Comment: Finally to decide to train pickpocket since everything is relatively easy and fast to level. The reason I am going to train pickpocket is because it's very low and and needs a higher level to be successful at power leveling. Also, I really don't want to go around stealing from people either so the less I steal the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a general sense, I focus on paying to level skills that would take a long time to accrue manually:

- Lockpicking
- Whatever armor I don't use often (e.g. Heavy Armor for a sneak thief),
- Conjuration
- Sneak

For the rest, I just alter my play style to have them level up quickly, or I [use a number of exploits](http://www.news-nerd.com/2011/11/guide-skyrim-bug-to-level-up-skills.html) to level them quickly.

I leveled up block extremely quickly after level 53 by going into a dwemer ruin with a Master Dwemer sphere and just let it wail on my light armor and on my shield, and healing myself with a restoration spell.  It took about 30 minutes, but I went from 50-100 in that time for block, and light armor went from 60-90.

Comment: Completing thieves guild gives you skeleton key making Lockpicking pointless?

Comment: You lose the key when you complete the Thieves' Guild quests.

Comment: @Doomsknight even with the skeleton key, Lockpicking skill gives you level experience.. which you will need if you want to reach the level cap.

Comment: thanks for the tips, George! I'll that for my block as I also need to get the armor up as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aiming for a level 70-something-do-everything-god-like character. So I train the skills I don't use. For example, I started out a mage (so I trained archery) and when I got level 100 destruction I switched to 2-handed heavy warrior (so I trained single-handed).

The beauty of Skyrim is: if you change your play style, it doesn't really matter.